# Multiple forms, one servlet - Design perspective

Tags: jsp, servlets

I would like to start a thread on handling the "multipe Form, one Servlet" scenario and discuss pros and cons. There are multiple use cases where this model could be deployed with a prime example being:

AccountDetails.jsp : contains multiple forms
UpdateAccountDetalsServlet : depending on which form was submitted, calls a DAO method to update the database.

Now the obvious solution here would be to pass a hidden parameter to the servlet and determine which form was submitted, but this doesn't feel right. Why?

I'd like to get some feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is fine. You can even use enums:

```
OperationType opType = OperationType.valueOf(request.getParameter("opType"));

switch(opType) {
  case SAVE..
  case DELETE..
}
```

In Spring MVC prior to the new restful model you could have a multi-action controller. There you had to pass a parameter in the URL, like `method=save`, and spring invoked the `save()` method on your object. This is something you can also implement, but it includes reflection.

Comment: Thanks - I am currently using enums actually. Would you rather use enums instead of one servlet per form/action ?

Comment: I personally would use a web framework like Spring MVC. But if not - yes, I'd use an enum. Actually - take a look at BalusC link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/)